What's the correct answer for $ \oint_{C} \frac{e^{1/z}}{z^{2} - 1} \, dz$?
$$
\oint_{C} \frac{e^{1/z}}{z^{2} - 1} \, dz,
$$
where $ C $ is the unit circle defined by $ |z| = 1 $.
The original question can be found under the answer from Ron Gordon's answer to "contour integral with singularity on the contour"
My math is not that great. Is there any math wizard here who would like look to at this issue?
(*Parametric z*)
contourF = E^(1/z) (z^2 - 1) /. {z -> E^(I t)}
Integrate[contourF, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]

This code tells me it's $-\pi$.
However, this code
f[z_] := E^(1/z) (z^2 - 1);
int = 2 Pi I Total[Residue[f[z], {z, #}] & /@ {0, 1}] // Simplify

generates this following error.
General::ivar: E^(I t) is not a valid variable.

I am using Mathematica  12.0
You can discuss both condition if you  want.
Condition 1.
circle $|z|=1$
Condition 2
circle $|z|=1$
with semi-circular notches of radius $\varepsilon$
cut into the circle at the poles $z = \pm 1$

Your code does not match your graphics (it doesn't have singularities at +-1)

@mikado Can you provide the correct  code? I have two version. The other one use  parametric, is that correct?

You are missing a "/" (I think)

Hmmm... interesting I got a different result than 0 provided in the answer on math.stackexchange.

(1) Ron's answer is that "the integral as posed does not exist." Do you miss that or not understand what it meant? (2) Did you mean a different answer, one to one of the other integrals? You didn't ask about those integrals, though. You ask about the integral that was posed in the linked Q&A

@MichaelE2 You can discuss both condition.

What's to discuss in "does not exist"? Which of the other conditions do you mean? You should make your post clearer, imo. As it stands, your question is not about two conditions.

@kile:  Do you mean a contour $re^{it}$ with $r<1$ and the other $r>1$?  If so then the integral abruptly changes from  $2 i \left(\frac{e}{2}-\frac{1}{2 e}\right) \pi$ inside unit circle to zero outside unit circle.   The Cauchy Principal Value using indented contours including/excluding poles at $\pm 1$ would confirm this abrupt change.   So that you can use Residue Theorem about poles to compute residue at the origin.

@MichaelE2 I updated this question. Take a look.

@josh I am focusing the contour $r = 1$, which is $\mid\ z \mid = 1 $

In 14.1 on Windows
ContourIntegrate[Exp[1/z]/(z^2 - 1), z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, r],  Assumptions -> r > 1]


0

ContourIntegrate[Exp[1/z]/(z^2 - 1), z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, 1],  PrincipalValue -> True]

returns the input and
ContourIntegrate[Exp[1/z]/(z^2 - 1), z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, r], Assumptions -> r < 1 && r > 0]


I (\[Pi]/E - E \[Pi])

Addition. The integral
$$ \oint_{C} \frac{e^{1/z}}{z^{2} - 1} \, dz,$$
where $C$ is the unit circumference does not exist. Up to Plemelj–Sokhotski relation, its principal value equals
Pi*I*(Residue[E^(1/z)/(z^2 - 1), {z, 1}]+ Residue[E^(1/z)/(z^2 - 1), {z, -1}])


I (-(1/(2 E)) + E/2) \[Pi]


Nice answer! how about the case when circle $|z|=1$
with semi-circular notches of radius $\varepsilon$
cut into the circle at the poles $z = \pm 1$

I have a hard  time understanding Plemelj–Sokhotski relation since my math is not very good, could you use something simple instead?

@kile: You wrote "how about the case when circle |z|=1 with semi-circular notches of radius ε cut into the circle at the poles z=±1 ?". The Plemelj–Sokhotski relation does it. I don't know "something simple instead".

Update to a simpler way:
Shift the interval to put the singularities in the middle. (Why? I guess symbolic analysis fails.)
contourF = E^(1/z)/(z^2 - 1) Dt[z, t] /. {z -> E^(I t)}
Integrate[contourF
  , {t, 0 - Pi/2, 2 \[Pi] - Pi/2}
  , PrincipalValue -> True] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
(I E^(E^(-I t) + I t))/(-1 + E^(2 I t))

{0.276803, -((I (-1 + E^2) \[Pi])/(2 E))}
*)


This is what I got too, but I do not think it agrees with Ron's result. If I understand his answer correctly his conclusion was that the integral is 0.

It's best if you can discuss both condition.

circle $|z|=1$
$\newline$

circle $|z|=1$
with semicircular notches of radius $\varepsilon$
cut into the circle at the poles $ z=\pm 1$


I don't get your result.
(*  -(((-1 + E^2) \[Pi])/(2 E))  <-- Ron's result *)
This is what I got
Integrate[-(1/2) E^Cos[t] Csc[t] Sin[Sin[t]], {t, -(\[Pi]/2),    0, \[Pi], (3 \[Pi])/2}, PrincipalValue -> True]

@azerbajdzan Ron's result for his integral is $\pi(e-e^{-1})$, no? He omits the factor of $-1/2$ (or I include it, depending on your point of view).

@MichaelE2 I see in his answer expression $\pi(e-e^{-1})$ but I do not think it is his final result. I agree there should be factor 1/2 as is in your answer.

@kile I don't have V12.2.

@azerbajdzan I guess don't know what you mean by the final result. It looks like the result I'm talking about.

@MichaelE2 Can you explain what this mean {t, 0 - Pi/2, 0, Pi, 2 \[Pi] - Pi/2}? I think it should be {t, 0 - Pi, 0, Pi, 2 \[Pi] }?

@Michael E2:  Superb!  I assume you concluded the real part is zero by symmetry.  Nice Exercise.  Impressive that Mathematica can solve these Principal valued integrals symbolically.

@josh To be fair, I assume Ron did that. Actually I gave up on contourF because it ran long and shifted attention to the imaginary part thinking it might be faster. It's not. I gave up on it, but left it running while I did something else, and what do you know. It turns out the straight shot Integrate[contourF  , {t, 0 - Pi/2, 0, Pi, 2 \[Pi] - Pi/2}  , PrincipalValue -> True] takes the same amount of time. But darn, Integrate[contourF  , {t, 0 - Pi/2, 2 \[Pi] - Pi/2}  , PrincipalValue -> True] takes 1.8 sec., which I just discovered. Ha!

I don't understand so much to-do about a problem already solved on MSE....If it weren't for seemingly having to shift the interval, this would be a works-as-described kind of question and answer.

Integrate[contourF, {t, -Pi/2, 0, Pi/2}, PrincipalValue -> True] +   Integrate[contourF, {t, Pi/2, Pi, 2*Pi + Pi/2},    PrincipalValue -> True] returns the input in 14.1 on Windows.

NIntegrate[contourF, {t, -Pi/2, 0, Pi/2}, Method -> "PrincipalValue",    WorkingPrecision -> 12] +   NIntegrate[contourF, {t, Pi/2, Pi, 2*Pi + Pi/2},    Method -> "PrincipalValue", WorkingPrecision -> 12] returns "NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in t near {t} = {6.28923134002}. NIntegrate obtained -8.71228890684-3.14290247147 I and 9.52312977601. for the integral and error estimates." and -8.52621801652-6.59600448430 I.

@user64494 It's a confusing syntax: For Integrate, do not specify the singularities in the integration path (apparently). For NIntegrate, specify all of the singularities (2 Pi is missing). [Example Integrate[1/x, {x, -1, 2}, PrincipalValue -> True] from docs fails if you add 0, Integrate[1/x, {x, -1, 0, 2}, PrincipalValue -> True]. Contrast with NIntegrate.]

@MichaelE2: Thank you. You are right.

This agrees with @MichaelE2 answer.
f[z_] := E^(1/z)/(z^2 - 1)

With[{z = E^(I t)}, 
  Integrate[f[z]* D[z, t], {t, a, Pi - a}, 
   Assumptions -> 0 < a < Pi/2]];
With[{z = E^(I t)}, 
  Integrate[f[z]* D[z, t], {t, Pi + a, 2 Pi - a}, 
   Assumptions -> 0 < a < Pi/2]];

Limit[%% + %, a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
N[%]


$$-\frac{i \left(e^2-1\right) \pi }{2 e}$$
0. - 3.692 I


Do you consider circle $|z|=1$
with semi-circular notches of radius $\varepsilon$
cut into the circle at the poles $z = \pm 1$?
Or circle $|z|=1 $ only?

I consider two half circles of $|z|=1$ which together form a complete circle as a->0 in a limit. It is a in my code, you call it $\varepsilon$.

Why did you divide the circle into half and combine them together later?
Why not handle it as a whole part in the beginning?

To avoid poles at $z = \pm 1$. The two half circles touch each other at these poles when a->0.

@kile ...also because these integrals diverge at poles.

modified
AsymptoticIntegrate evaluates wrong result (thanks @azerbajdzan)
 asy = AsymptoticIntegrate[E^(1/z)/(z^2 - 1) Dt[z, t] /. {z -> E^(I t)}, {t, eps , 2 \[Pi] - eps}, eps -> 0]

 Limit[asy, eps -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
 (* -(3/2) I E \[Pi]=-12.8096 I *)

Integrate evalutes correct result
int =  Integrate[E^(1/z)/(z^2 - 1) Dt[z, t] /. {z -> E^(I t)}, {t, eps,  \[Pi] - eps} ] + 
Integrate[E^(1/z)/(z^2 - 1) Dt[z, t] /. {z -> E^(I t)}, {t, Pi +eps,2 \[Pi] - eps} ] // Simplify[#, eps > 0] &
Limit[int, eps -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]  
(*-((I (-1 + E^2) \[Pi])/(2 E))*)

numerical test
eps = 10^-10;
NIntegrate[E^(1/z)/(z^2 - 1) Dt[z, t] /.  z -> E^(I t), {t, eps, Pi - eps }] + 
NIntegrate[E^(1/z)/(z^2 - 1) Dt[z, t] /.  z -> E^(I t), {t,  Pi + eps, 2 Pi - eps }] 
(*2.99088*10^-6 - 3.692 I*)


So what is the conclusion of the numerical test, since the numeric values do not agree?

@azerbajdzan The numeric values agree well with MichaelE and your answers, result of AsymptoticIntegrateunfortunately not.

Nice and succinct!  Pretty powerful statement we can make now I think:  $$
\text{PV}\mathop{\oint}_{|z|=1} \frac{e^{1/z}}{z^2-1}=-\frac{i(e^2-1)\pi}{2e}
$$

@josh Thanks for your comment!

@UlrichNeumann The code give me error.
Integrate::idiv: Integral of (I E^(E^(-I t)+I t))/(-1+E^(2 I t)) does not converge on {eps,-eps+\[Pi]}. 

@kile Mathematica v12.2 evaluates without error. What is your version?

@UlrichNeumann v12.0

You can not use the calculus of residues because Exp[1/z] has not a pole at zero, but an essential singularity.
Then, a contour integral is defined by:
Integrate[f[path[t]] path'[t],{t,tstart,tend}]

Therefore, you are missing the path'[t] term in your code.
Further, there is a function in MMA for contour integration. E.g.
ContourIntegrate[Exp[1/z]/(z^2 - 1), z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, 2]]

0

Finally, ContourIntegrate[Exp[1/z]/(z^2 - 1), z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, 1]] does not converge because there is a double pole on the path.

what is path'[t]?

But this contourF = E^(1/z) (z^2 - 1) /. {z -> E^(I t)} is not function of t

ContourIntegrate[Exp[1/z]/(z^2 - 1), z \[Element] Circle[{0, 0}, R],   Assumptions -> R > 0] gives: ConditionalExpression[-I E \[Pi], R <= 1] ?

path' [t] is the derivative of the path (or contour): z=path[t]
